# The annulus with with antipodal points on the outer circle identified gives a mobius strip

Tags: algebraic-topology

I ve been told that the real projective plane of dimension two can be expresses as the union of a disk and a mobius strip. The only way that this makes sense to me is that if an annulus with with antipodal points on the outer circle identifies gives a mobius strip. But I can't see if this is true can anyone please explain
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, attaching a disk to the moebius strip along the boundary circle of the strip gives something homotopy equivalent to $\Bbb RP^2$. This follows from deformation retracting the moebius strip to it's boundary circle, which  results the space $D^2 \cup_f S^1$ with $f$ being a degree $2$ map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see how they are the same by following these drawings:

[image]

Comment: amazing thank you very much

Comment: The Projective plane is the quotient of the 2 sphere by the antipodal map. A strip around the equator maps to a Mobious band, The two polar caps are identified into a single disk and are attached to the Mobius band along its boundary circle.

Comment: Shouldn't the green arrow in the top center diagram be pointing left?

Comment: @Arcinde: you're right, I edited the picture. Thanks.